# Fixing elements to the bottom of the screen in mobile safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile-safari

I'm building a mobile app that has a modal on the bottom of the screen. That modal has a text input.

I'm trying to use CSS only to make the modal always fixed to the bottom of the screen and it works great UNTIL the keyboard is opened. It covers the modal and it's content, because it seems that the viewport "bottom" stays in the same position.

I have looked around some changes on the viewport meta and env(safe-area-inset-bottom), but ended up with a quirky JS solution tied to the resize of the virtalViewport, which lags when the keyboard opens/closes.

Any idea?